# Does datatype length affect the performance?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a very general question regarding length of the data type. suppose i have assigned a `varchar(2500)` and i am using only up-to 100 bytes. will the rest of the unused length specified by me affect any thing?

Comment: The answer from http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/1782 might be helpful.

Comment: you will find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1243018/892788) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353159/does-the-database-maximum-field-length-affect-performance) useful.

Answer (score 0):

`VARCHAR` will take only 100. Rest of memory will be used by another fields.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this reference(mysql) : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html